# ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Here is my `df.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1162 entries, 0 to 1161
Data columns (total 61 columns):
 #   Column                                        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                        --------------  -----  
 0   Algorithms&DataStructures                     428 non-null    float64
 1   C/C++Programming                              688 non-null    float64
 2   Calculus1                                     835 non-null    float64
 3   Calculus2                                     752 non-null    float64
 4   Calculus3                                     366 non-null    float64
 5   ChemistryLaboratory                           497 non-null    float64
 6   ChemistryforEngineers                         823 non-null    float64
 7   ComputerArchitecture                          433 non-null    float64
```

And this is the function used to impute the NaN value:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

# function that imputes a dataframe 
def impute_knn(df):
    
    ''' inputs: pandas df containing feature matrix '''
    ''' outputs: dataframe with NaN imputed '''
    # imputation with KNN unsupervised method
    # separate dataframe into numerical/categorical
    ldf = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])           # select numerical columns in df
    ldf_putaside = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])  # select categorical columns in df
    # define columns w/ and w/o missing data
    cols_nan = ldf.columns[ldf.isna().any()].tolist()         # columns w/ nan 
    cols_no_nan = ldf.columns.difference(cols_nan).values     # columns w/o nan 

    for col in cols_nan:                
        imp_test = ldf[ldf[col].isna()]   # indicies which have missing data will become our test set
        imp_train = ldf.dropna()          # all indicies which which have no missing data 
        model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5)  # KNR Unsupervised Approach
        knr = model.fit(imp_train[cols_no_nan], imp_train[col])
        ldf.loc[df[col].isna(), col] = knr.predict(imp_test[cols_no_nan])
    
    return pd.concat([ldf,ldf_putaside],axis=1)
```

I got it from: [Bayesian Regression | House Price Prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/code/shtrausslearning/bayesian-regression-house-price-prediction/notebook)

However, when I apply it to my dataframe, it reports an error:

---

Full error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-284-b13fac408835> in <module>
----> 1 df2 = impute_knn(df)
      2 # looks like we have a full feature matrix
      3 df2.info()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    663 
    664         if all(isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) for dtype in dtypes_orig):
--> 665             dtype_orig = np.result_type(*dtypes_orig)
    666 
    667     if dtype_numeric:

<__array_function__ internals> in result_type(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required
```

I'd love to hear your comment! Thank you!

Comment: Dont you want to try [KNNImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) from scikit-learn itself? It also offers great example.

Comment: I just wonder why I can't apply my dataframe to that function. I think that my dataframe has a null value in every row, so it can't apply. I will try KNNImputer. Thank you